# Customise Parse push notification - Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am new to use Parse push notifications for Android. I have successfully integrated parse push notification to my project and tested. It works fine, but I have a few questions related to this push notification service, which I am not able to find in the Parse documentation.

1. How do I customise the push notification's sound?
2. How do I send a push notification from the device itself, without using the parse console?
3. What is the unique Id that I must save in order to perform the above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I customise the push notification's sound?

By default when a push notification is received the `BroadcastReceiver` specified in `AndroidManifest.xml` with intentfilter specified `<action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />` is called.

Parse.com provides a BroadCastReceiver `com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver` which just sounds the default notification sound of the device. It does not have code for a specific notification sound, if you want to change the notification sound for push by parse you would have to implement a new BroadCastReceiver with the intentfilter specified above and have the below code for a custom sound(its only a partial code for demonstration):

```
Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
builder.setSound(alarmSound);
```

> How do I send a push notification from the device itself, without
>   using the parse console?

Push notification can be sent from a device to another device or from console to devices. Every Parse application installed on a device registered for push notifications has an associated `Installation` object. The Installation object is where you store all the data needed to target push notifications. Now there would be many app users and you would want to target a specific user, for eg an app collects username at the first installation of the app and sets it in Installation object shown as below:

```
 ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
  installation.put("userName", "ranjith");  //mobile 1
  installation.saveInBackground();
```

Now to send notification to the username "ranjith" you would need to create a `ParseQuery` object with the condition **-username=ranjith** shown as below, this would send a push notification to username "ranjith".

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
    ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();//mobile2
    pushQuery.whereEqualTo("userName", "ranjith");
    ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
    push.setQuery(pushQuery); // Set our Installation query
    push.setMessage("My first notification");
```

> What is the unique Id that I must save in order to perform the above?

These are the 2 unique ids present within parse installation object and these are generated by parse and you would not need to worry about it, to target a specific user you can add a unique id/username field in Installation object as specified above,

- `installationId`: Unique Id for the device used by Parse (readonly).
- `appIdentifier`: A unique identifier for this installation's client
  application. This parameter is not supported in Android.(readonly)

Comment: Thanks a lot for such wonderful answer Ranjith. I have one doubt in the second question. Now the installation.put("userName","ranjith") will be stored in the parse server ? Am I right ? So that the other person can just use this query to fetch the User by his "userName" and send him push notification ?

Comment: Thats right. It will be saved in parse server under installation object. You can see it in the parse.com console.

Comment: Ok great. I have one more doubt. Is the userName unique ? If not, how to make it unique.

Comment: Bro, I tried to use it and i am successful in registering the new userName, but I am unable to send the push notification from another device.

Comment: You need to follow the guidelines mentioned here https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/native/new

Comment: Hi Ranjith, i read this and that same code Works for Xamarin android Project ?and how can i send the push from all the devices just the same we can do by parse console ?Thanks! @ɥʇᴉɾuɐɹ

Comment: Not very sure about xmarin... To send push from device to device you have to use parseinstallation query as shown in above answer

Comment: @ɥʇᴉɾuɐɹ how do you get `builder` inside custom `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver` ?